# Set image as src to an image html element after fetching it with fetch

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

I try to fetch an image protected by Bearer token and I want to set it to the src property of an image element

```
 var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + getAccessToken());
  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
    redirect: 'follow'
  };
  fetch("__AUTH_HOST__/storage/o/user/" + getCookie('user_id') + '/' + username + '.png', requestOptions)
      .then(response => {
        if(response.status == 200){
            document.getElementById('image_id').src = something
        }
      }).catch(error => console.error(error));
```

is there any way to achieve this? or should I store it somehow locally?

Comment: you'll need to fetch the actual image data - there's actually an example of how to do exactly this in the documentation for fetch [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#fetching_an_image)

Comment: @Bravo you are absolutely right! thank you!